# iOS6 Maps, MISSING the Detail Disclosure Button (the blue chevron) on all my maps! How to get it back

Tags: iphone, mapkit, ios6, ios6-maps

My understanding was there was no problems moving to iOS 6 maps. But for some reason, the Detail Disclosure Button is now MISSING in my map App. Is there a way to get this back.  Wow, totally unexpected. This has been working for years, so all delegates are fine.

```
#pragma mark MKMapViewDelegate
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"REUSEME"] autorelease];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
    pin.animatesDrop = YES;
    return nil;
} else {
    [pin setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen];
}

pin.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;
pin.animatesDrop = YES;
pin.canShowCallout = YES;

return pin;
}
```

Comment: I've got this as well.  Find that if I leave the app running for a bit, zoom the pins offscreen and back again the callout works once more.  Seems a bug in the compatibility but there must be an ordering issue that'll fix it?  I'll post the answer if I find it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now in iOS 6 you have to set the delegate before adding the annotation to the mapView

seen in here: http://www.openradar.me/12346693

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and setting the MapView delegate in the Storyboard did the trick for me, callout arrows now working:)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I only put the delegate after annotation and work perfectly!

```
mapView.delegate = self;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:ann];
```

Tks,
Cauca

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this problem and the only difference I can see between your code and mine is in the creation of the MKPinAnnotationPinView object as I try to dequeue it first:

```
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I use the same code as the first answer:

MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin =(MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MyPin"];

I also noticed other problems since updating to xcode 4.5/iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

What I have noticed in mapKit for iOS 6 is that the timing is essential. Setting the MKMapView´s delegate to late (i.e. in viewDidLoad), the map will use default annotation style for annotations already added.
The solution for me was to move the mapView.delegate = self, to the -(void)loadView method.

Answer (score 0):

@ErCa As per iOS documentation, you should never call loadView unless you are building a custom view.

The problem lies elsewhere. I have it as well and will post an answer once I find it.

@ed-potter Are you targeting iOS4? I'm asking because you autorelease the MKPinAnnotationView which is not necessary with ARC.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well.  It is true that the MKMapView delegate needs to be set earlier than viewDidLoad: now for some reason.  What I ended up doing is setting the mapView delegate within my setMapView: function.

So for the view controller that contains the MKMapView, I had the following property:

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

and so I put within the setMapView function:

-(void)setMapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
{

```
_mapView = mapView;

self.mapView.delegate = self;//needed to move setting of the mapView delegate here because they changed when the viewForAnnotations delegate function is called when Apple went to iOS 6 and changed the maps App.  Now all of the annotations are loaded and the views for those annotations are set up before the View Controller even calls viewDidLoad.

[self updateMapView];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was also setting `self.mapView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad` but `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` was not getting called, so my `leftCalloutAccessoryView` was not getting the `UIImageView` I specified.  I went back to review Ray Wenderlich's [Introduction to MapKit in iOS 6 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial) and found this:

> First select MainStoryboard.storyboard. Then set the View Controller
>   (right at the top of the list) as the delegate of the map view by
>   control clicking on the map view, and dragging a line from the
>   delegate entry to the View Controller.